# xml processing options in python

Tags: python, xml

I am currently writing a non-web program using mostly python and have gotten to the point where I need to create a structure for save and settings files.

I decided to use xml over creating my own format but have come into a bit of a barrier when trying to figure out what to use to actually process the xml. I want to know if I can get some of the pros and cons about packages that are available for python since there are a lot and I'm not entirely sure which ones seem best from just looking at the documentation.

I basically want to know if there is a package or library that will let me write and read data from an xml file with relative ease by just knowing what the tag name I'm looking for is.

P.S. My app is mostly geared to be used on Linux if it makes any difference.

Comment: A list of options: http://wiki.python.org/moin/PythonXml

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your data is only for the use of your Python programs, pickle might be an easier solution.

Comment: If you have a problem and use XML, then you have two problems. :-)

Comment: It turned out to be really easy this way. I made a user defined class with just data and used pickle to save and load it. It's great and scalable to boot. ;D

Answer (score 0):

Don't use xml -- use yaml or json -- some would argue xml has outlived it's useful life...

That being said, I like ElementTree:

```
import xml.etree.cElementTree as ET
fname = 'foo.xml'
root = ET.parse(open(fname))
... yada yada...
```